# максимальное число из MongoDB(Python)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

вопрос по Mongodb

мне нужно вывести максимальное число из БД, структура кода вот такая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вывести максимальное значение cash, сам я в Mongodb, да и вообщем с Базами начал работать относительно недавно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076382/mongodb-how-to-get-max-value-from-collections

Comment: Выдает ошибку
**
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
**